# ng2-chart with Angular 4: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, systemjs, ng2-charts

The idea is to use **chart.js** with **Angular 4 and ng2-charts**. 
I'm working with the example [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/), but i can't get it to work.

I get the following error message:

> Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

I already imported it into app.module.ts as most posts suggest with this error. Is there something i'm missing?

...component.html:

```
<div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
        [data]="data"
        [labels]="labels"
        [chartType]="type">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

...component.ts

```
...
labels:string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail-Order Sales'];
data:number[] = [350, 450, 100];
type:string = 'doughnut';
...
```

index.html:

```
<script src="lib/chart.js/dist/chart.js"></script>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
imports: [
    ...
    ChartsModule,
    ...
],
```

system.js

```
map: {
    ...
    'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts/bundles'
},
packages: {
    ...
    'ng2-charts': {
         defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/router": "^4.3.0",
  "@angular/upgrade": "4.3.0",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
  "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
  "@types/jquery": "2.0.44",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
  "core-js": "2.4.1",
  "ej-angular2": "15.1.41",
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
  "jquery": "3.2.1",
  "jsrender": "0.9.84",
  "pretty-checkbox": "2.2.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "5.4.0",
  "syncfusion-javascript": "15.1.41",
  "systemjs": "0.20.12",
  "typescript": "^2.4.1",
  "zone.js": "0.8.10",
  "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
  "chart.js": "2.6.0"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After serveral hours of try and error i got it working. I changed the following things:

app.module.ts:

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
```

system.js:

```
map: {
    ...
    'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts/bundles'
},
packages: {
    ...
    'ng2-charts': {
         main: 'ng2-charts.umd.min.js',
         defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not able to find system.js file.